# Алгоритм нахождения наипохожих названий в 2х string массивах

Tags: php, алгоритм, поиск

У меня есть 2 таблицы с информацией об учебных заведениях, нужен такой скрипт который бы смог найти схожие учебные заведения в этих двух таблицах. (Далее я буду сравнивать значения)

Сначала я получаю просто названия уч заведений = 2 string arrays с названиями
и создаю цикл по первому массиву и нахожу наилучший элемент из второго и в конце получаю массив наисхожих пар.

Нашел функцию similar_text(), 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php
но работает неэффективно.. Вот пример

```
<?php
    $var_1 = 'МГУ имени М.В. Ломоносова - Московский государственный университет имени М.В. Ломоносова'; 
    $var_2 = 'Федеральное государственное бюджетное образовательное учреждение высшего образования Московский государственный университет имени М.В. Ломоносова'; 
    $var_3 = 'МГУТУ им. К.Г. Разумовского - Московский государственный университет технологий и управления имени К.Г. Разумовского';

    similar_text($var_1, $var_2, $percent1);
    echo $percent1; //64.530892448513 

    similar_text($var_1, $var_3, $percent2);
    echo $percent2; //71.122994652406
    ." ".
?>
```

Как мы можем заметить $var_1 и $var_2 схожие названия получили 64% схожести, когда как $var_1 и $var_3 разные названия получили выше процент схожести

Имеются ли какие нибудь идеи/предложения?

Comment: Надо сначала понять какая у вас задача? Поиск разных написаний одного и того же вуза? В этом случае надо иметь наготове несколько вариантов написания для каждого ВУЗа и сравнивать с ними.

Comment: Если тупо проверка на наличие слов то: 1. Приведите в ловеркейс, 2. Експлод на по пробелу, 3. `array_intersect()`, 4. Размер массива с шага 3 делим на размер массива который главный и умножаем на 100

Comment: Ivan Bolnikh, Изменил описание и добавил задачу
num8er, спасибо за идею - опробую ее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Для начала удаляете из строк всё, кроме букв и цифр и пробелов (множественные пробелы схлопываете в один)
2. Разбиваете строки в массив по пробелу, сортируете и склеиваете обратно в нижнем регистре `mb_strtoupper(implode(" ", sort(explode(" ", $string))));`
3. Вычисляете [расстояние Левенштейна](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.levenshtein.php) (или [степень похожести по Оливеру](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.similar-text.php)) между всеми парами строк
4. Делаете какие-то выводы. Например, если результат 5, а длина наибольшей строки 30, то, скорее всего, это один и тот же ВУЗ.

В целом нужно поэкспериментировать и найти оптимальное соотношение попаданий/ложных срабатываний.

Comment: Получил сделать поделюсь немного опытом:
1) sort не работал, использовал usort
2) Левенштейн плохо работал, использовал Оливера